# Use of prepositions "at" and "in"

Tags: prepositions

Which of these two is right?

> This project can raise the sale at the global level
>
> This project can raise the sale in the global level

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct. I suspect what you mean to say is

> This project may increase global sales.

If you want to stay as close as possible to the original, then say

> This project can raise sales at the global level.

The latter will be understood and sound idiomatic even if a bit verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The usual preposition to use with "level" is "at". Something is **at** a particular level. I would use the plural of "sale" too, and omit the definite article, since "sales" is general.

> This project can raise sales **at** the global level.

The preposition "in" can be used with a different noun, say "market". In this case

> This project can raise sales **in** the global market.